# adding a classList to each element at a time in a array - plain js

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm new to javascript and I've been trying something that although basic i can't really seem to understand why it isn't working.

I have three images and one button. Everytime I click that same button i want one of the images to disappear (using classList to add a Css class of display: none).

I'm trying to use the for loop but when I click the button they disappear at the same time. I've tried to create a variable inside the loop to store the index value but it returns an error.

Help please !!!   Thanks

\\ Js

```
window.onload = function(){


        var button = document.querySelector("button");
        var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("#imagens img");

        button.addEventListener("click",function(){

            for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){

                imgs[i].classList.add("hidden");    

                //var currentImg = this.imgs[i];
                //currentImg.classList.add("hidden");       
            }
        })      
    };

\\\ CSS
    .hidden{
        display:none;
    }

    #images{        
        width:400px;
        height:200px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }


    #images img{
        width:110px;
        height:100px;   
    }

    button{
        margin:100px auto;
    }

\\\ HTML

<div id="images">
    <img src="https://media.defense.gov/2018/Jul/11/2001941257/780/780/0/180711-F-EF974- 0115.JPG" alt="">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3267/2590079513_12e2c73226_b.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Poinsettia_tree.jpg/360px-Poinsettia_tree.jpg" alt="">  
    <div>
        <button type="button">change</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: If you click the button, what should actually happen?? What is your expectation on button click??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time the button is clicked, you loop through all the images so you add to all of them the hidden class. What you need to do is to create a global variable that can store the index of the last image you hid.
And when you click the button, you add the hidden class to the image at the index + 1 then increment that index for the next image. You don't need to have a for loop for that.

You also mistyped in your query selector, it should be

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("#images img");
```

instead of

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("#imagens img");
```

So here's what you should have :

```js
let index = -1;

window.onload = function(){


        var button = document.querySelector("button");
        var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("#images img");

        button.addEventListener("click",function(){
          index++;
          imgs[index].classList.add("hidden");
        })
    };
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#images {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#images img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
}

button {
  margin: 100px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img src="https://media.defense.gov/2018/Jul/11/2001941257/780/780/0/180711-F-EF974- 0115.JPG" alt="">
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3267/2590079513_12e2c73226_b.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Poinsettia_tree.jpg/360px-Poinsettia_tree.jpg" alt="">
  <div>
    <button type="button">change</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` for this requirement and update the `for` loop inside `button` click like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      imgs[index].classList.add("hidden");
    }, i * 1500);
  })(i);
}
```

This way `hidden` class would be added to one image at a time after a delay of `1500` ms.